# Image sizing problems across different resolutions

Tags: css

I have a two-part header. The left 20% holds an image (our logo) and the right 80% is navigation, etc.

The width of the header itself, as well as either part of it, is expressed with percentages. The height is expressed with `em`. This results in a quite fluid layout. The only problematic area is the logo - since it is not the same dimensions as the container, it will go from fitting perfectly in certain resolutions, to getting squeezed too small and being forced up top on other resolutions.

The only CSS applied to the image is a width inside the container and a margin.

How can I ensure that the logo fills the entire container regardless of resolution?

Answer (score 0):

You'd give the logo a percentage width as well (likely 100% to fill the container). Keep in mind that in doing that, you are at the mercy of the browser's image scaling abilities which may produce less than desirable results in some cases.

That said, it sounds like you are scaling with two entirely different variables: horizontal scaling based on the viewport width, and vertical scaling based on the font size settings. While I applaud your goal for flexibility, maybe rethink the need to scale the logo itself. Not everything on the page needs to scale.

Comment: The image has a percentage width already. Are you saying I should make the header have an absolute pixel height and width? Or should I make it a percentage height (which in my experience is harder to work with)?

Comment: You are scaling height and width disproportionately. As such, I see no easy way to scale your logo image with CSS alone. You could use JS...grab the height and width of the container, and then calculate what scale the image should be at to best fit based on the aspect ratios of the container. But that seems like a lot of complicated technology for what seems more like a visual design issue.

Comment: What would you propose as the simplest solution?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to redesign the look and layout of the header so that it doesn't require the logo to be scaled to look good. But I say that as someone that does a lot of visual/logo design, so I'm biased in that direction. That said, few, if any sites are built so that the branding elements scale like that. I'm guessing others have tried and given up as well. If you could show a mock-up or link to your site, we could offer more specific answers/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider adding a min-width to your image or it's container to make sure it only gets "squeezed" to a certain extent.